# Resizable mask for resizable UIView with fixed transparency borders

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, mask

I have UIView that will dynamically change your height and I want apply mask which make borders (with constantly size) of UIView transparency, this mask must be resizable too. Image example: http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/e/4/upload/d6382af2.png

Please help me do it

Answer (score 0):

if i understood right, you must write this:

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeA, sizeB);
myView.center = self.view.center;
```

let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to stretch the view without distorting the borders, set the image to:

```
myImageView.image = [myMaskImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:xmarginSize topCapHeight:ymarginSize];
```